# understanding the conditional expectation

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Given a sigma field $\mathfrak{g}$ and a random variable $X$. A conditional expectation of $X$ is defined as $E(X|\mathfrak{g})$ and this conditional expectation is $\mathfrak{g}$ measurable.Now define an indicator function $\mathfrak{1}_G$ where $G\in\mathfrak{g}$. Consider the expression $E(X|\mathfrak{g})\cdot1_G$. If I have an element $l\in\mathfrak{g}$ and $l\not\subseteq G$, then the  expression $(E(X|\mathfrak{g})\cdot1_G)(l)$ means  $E(X|l)\cdot0$. Am I correct on this?

edit:
changed $E(X|\mathfrak{g})\cdot1_G(l)$ to $(E(X|\mathfrak{g})\cdot1_G)(l)$

clarifying:

$(E(X|\mathfrak{g})\cdot1_G)(l)$
the $\cdot$ notation here means multiplication

Comment: $1_G(l)$ has no meaning. If $A$ and $B$ are sets then $1_A(B)$ does not make snese.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. If I instead have $l\in \mathfrak{g}$,meaning $l$ is an element in $\mathfrak{g}$. Do I then get $(E(X|\mathfrak{g})\cdot1_G)(l)=(E(X|\mathfrak{g})(l)\cdot1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Since $E(X \mid \mathfrak{g})$ is a $\mathfrak{g}$-random variable, I think it would be better to write
$$(E(X \mid \mathfrak{g}) \cdot 1_G)(l) = E(X \mid \mathfrak{g})(l) \cdot 0.$$
As far as I know, something like "$E(X \mid l)$" is not defined.